# Show Dynamic colors on recyclerview list numberings

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-imageview

I want to achieve something like this:
 [See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK1Dn.jpg)

A list with circular shape drawable with a fill of a light variant color of the image tint color
I have tried `textrdrawable`library but it does not give me the same. I have tried the following code too but to no avail:

```
public int darkenColor(int color) {
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
        hsv[2] *= 0.8f; // value component
        color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
        return color;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] mColors = {

   "5E97F6",
   "9CCC65",
   "FF8A65",
   "9E9E9E",
   "9FA8DA",
   "90A4AE",
   "AED581",
   "F6BF26",
   "FFA726",
   "4DD0E1",
   "BA68C8",
   "A1887F",
};

// all colors used by gmail application :)
```

[light colors](https://www.december.com/html/spec/colorshades.html)

```
 // genrating random num from 0 to 11 because you can add more or less 


   int i1 = new Random().nextInt(11);

//genrating shape with colors 

GradientDrawable draw = new GradientDrawable();
    draw.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    draw.setColor(Color.parseColor ("#"+mColors[i1]));

// assigning to textview 
contact_name_circle.setBackground(draw); //textview
```